# jquery ui spinner change style of one specific spinner

Tags: class, jquery-ui, spinner

I want to remove the `ui-corner-tr` and `ui-corner-br` classes from one specific spinner with an id of `test` and a class of `testSpinner` as an example.

I tried... and many combinations of classes with no luck.

```
$('.ui-spinner .testSpinner').removeClass('.ui-corner-tr');
$('#test').removeClass('.ui-corner-tr');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It can be an order issue: maybe the jqueryUI library loads after your code, nullifying it.

(I'm just guessing... You should provide more details).

Answer (score 0):

the `removeClass` method does not require CSS selector names, just class names.

```
$('.ui-spinner .testSpinner').removeClass('ui-corner-tr');
$('#test').removeClass('ui-corner-tr');
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/